# help defining a generic method along with expression tree parameter

Tags: c#, generics, expression-trees

Suppose I have:

```
class Person
{
[ColumnAttribute("ID"]
    public int Id;
[ColumnAttribute("Name"]
public string Name;
[ColumnAttribute("DateOfBirth"]
    public date BirthDate;
}
```

i want to create a method that will be called as following

```
GetPropertyColumn<Person>(e=>e.Name)
```

this method will return a string that is defined by the ColumnAttribute attribute.
the problem is that i am not able to define this method.
i tried

```
public string GetPropertyColumn<T,U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> Lamda)
```

but the problem is that i can only specify the T and not the U so its not working.
any help?
thanks

### Edit:

thanks for the answers but i got a lot of answers in which you need to instantinate Person but i dont want to.
because i only want to know the column given a property defined inside a Class.

Comment: So if you have `GetPropertyColumn<Person>(e=>e.Name)
` in your code what results you are expect?

Comment: @Anton Semenov: a return of string with the value of "Name", which is the value of the columnattribute defined on the name field

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer so now it straight you was looking for

Answer (score 2):

**[EDIT 3]**

```
    public static string GetPropertyColumn<T>(Expression<Func<T,object>> f)
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);

        MemberExpression memberExpression = null;

        if (f.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        {
            memberExpression = ((UnaryExpression)f.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
        else if (f.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            memberExpression = f.Body as MemberExpression;
        }

        string name = memberExpression.Member.Name;

        System.Reflection.FieldInfo fi = t.GetField(name);
        object[] attrs = fi.GetCustomAttributes(true);

        foreach (var attr in attrs)
        {
            ColumnAttribute columnAttr = attr as ColumnAttribute;
            if (columnAttr != null)
            {
                return columnAttr.Name;
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

using:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetPropertyColumn<Person>(e => e.Name));
```

Comment: i dont want to instantinate Person nor specify the type of property.

Comment: this will work, but again the main idea was to use expression query so that the code is strongly typed , and you will have autocomplete too. so this is different from what i want :)

Comment: I just understand what you are really desire. Yes it can be done, I have edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you have a generic method with 2 generic types (T and U) then both most be specified, or both most be inferred. If that isn't possible, consider an expression taking `Func<T,object>` (remove U), and remove the cast/convert node from the expression tree when inspecting it at runtime. You can also do things to make both types inferred, but that may need more of a refactor.

Answer (score 1):

Make it an extension method:

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string GetPropertyColumn<T,U>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, U>> selector)
    {
        ... // whatever
    }
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
Person person = ...
string propertyColumn = person.GetPropertyColumn(p => p.Name);
```

You don't need to specify T, because it's inferred from the first parameter, and you don't need to specify U either because it is inferred from the return type of the lambda

Note that you don't *need* to define it as an extension method, it could also be a normal method. You would then use it like that:

```
Person person = ...
string propertyColumn = GetPropertyColumn(person, p => p.Name);
```

Comment: the problem is that i dont want to instantinate Person. because i wont be using it after that.

Comment: Then don't: `default(Person).GetPropertyColumn(p => p.Name);`. It doesn't matter if this parameter is null, since it's not actually used in the method. It's only there to allow the compiler to infer the type